# Detect pentagon in image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

## Problem:

> Given a UK Energy Performance Certificate (EPC) image, detect the pentagons containing integers between 1 and 100.

(these are *isosceles right pentagons*)

## Example EPC image 1:

```
     img1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcpnr.png"]
```

[image]

## desired output given `img1`:

[image]

### Background:

I hope to use a neural net to classify the pentagons in order to parse the EPC certificates. I have tried regular OCR, but this has turned out to be unreliable.

## Other EPC images:

These can be found in the `bestiary` folder in [this github repo](https://github.com/ccosnett/epc_parser/tree/master/assets/bestiary).

They can be loaded in mathematica by the following code:

```
path="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ccosnett/epc_parser/master/assets/bestiary/";
imgs = path <> # & /@ {
                        "102489965-2-ei-rating.png"
                      , "102492044-1-epc.jpg"
                      , "102519884-1-epc-graphs.jpg"
                      , "102729176-2-eir.jpeg"
                      , "102984668-1-epc-rating-graph.png"
                      , "103003823-1-epc.gif"
                      , "103187228-4-epc-rating-graph.png"
                      , "103309151-1-ee-rating.png"
                      , "105825026-1-epc-1.png"
                      , "105825038-1-epc-1.jpeg"
                      , "105829613-1-epc-1.png"
                      , "105835280-1-epc-1.jpeg"
                      , "108300254-1-epc-rating-graph.png"
                      , "108386993-1-environment-impact.jpg"
                      , "108386993-2-energy-efficiency.jpg"
                      , "test-1-12.png"
                      , "test-81-29.png"
                      , "test-88-1.png"};
images = Import /@ imgs
```

here is what they look like:

[image]

## Attempt 1:

I learned from the minimal documentation of the new [`ImageBoundingBoxes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageBoundingBoxes.html) that I can search for [`Entity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity.html)'s in images

The only one I could get to work was `Entity["Concept", "StopSign::wp7bc"]` but this only worked in one of my EPC images :( But this is nevertheless an interesting route to explore.

```
ImageBoundingBoxes[im1, Entity["Concept", "StopSign::wp7bc"]]
```

[image]

`Lamina` also looked promising, but is unfortunately not a searchable Entity at this time:

[image]

## Attempt 2:

[`FindImageText`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindImageText.html) seems to be too unreliable. And has to be used in conjunction with OCR and some logic to check if it has picked up the numbers on the pentagons:

```
hh[i_] := HighlightImage[i, FindImageText[#, "Word", AcceptanceThreshold -> 0] &];
hh /@ images
```

[image]

I would really appreciate some ideas :)

Comment: Convolve your image with pentagons of the matching size and orientation then select peaks.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go.